# Node.js grouping stdout from chid_process c application

Tags: c, node.js

I'm connecting a remote client to a c application via a node.js service and am having trouble separating the `printf()` statements from the c application when output from the node.js app.

When the `printf()` statements happen in quick succession, the node.js application prints them together. This is causing errors for the client parsing that output.

As I'm new to c and still early in node.js, my testing has lead me to guess that the issue is related to how node.js handles the `stdout` stream from the `child_process`.

I should also note that the output is not consistently incorrect. There are a few places in the code where it's more variable and correlated to the speed of user inputs (this is for a game). The example I've shared below is the case where the output most consistently incorrect.

I've tried:

- Running the c program directly. (This gives me the expected [correct] result)
- Adjusting the buffer size in c with `setvbuf` (Unexpected result from the node.js application)
- Running the c application from node with the synchronous and asynchronous versions of both `spawn` and `exec` (Unexpected result from the node.js application)

Here's a portion of the c application:

```c
void readPin(int outputPin){

  if(output[lightPins[light]] == outputPin){
    reportGameStatus("light match");
    lightSuccess();
  }
  ...
}

void lightSuccess(){
  reportGameStatus("light success");
  ...

}

void reportGameStatus(char* event){
  printf("{"
        "\"event\":\"%s\","
      "}\n",
        event
      );

    fflush(stdout);
}
```

And here's the node.js portion:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var process = spawn("./cApplication");

process.stdout.on('data',function(msg){
    console.log('stdout: ' + msg);
        ...
});
```

This results in the following output from the node.js application:

```
stdout: {"event":"light match"}{"event":"light success"}
```

Expected result:

```
stdout: {"event":"light match"}
stdout: {"event":"light success"}
```

Comment: Your listed output is not what your `reportGameStatus()` function prints out...

Comment: @Shawn The errant output is variable and does not always show up. There are a few cases in the application where this happens less consistently and dependent on the speed of user inputs. The case I've shared here is most consistently incorrect, however. I'll edit the post with that info.